# Select box not set properly using backbone code

Tags: html, backbone.js, drop-down-menu

Option is not setting properly.

I have a select box

```
<select id="opentoall" name="opentoall">
                                       <option selected="1" value="true">Public</option>
                                       <option value="false">Viewers</option>
</select>
```

Now i am trying to set the select box using the following backbone code but it's not setting properly.

```
this.$el.html(this.template({
            model: this.model.toJSON()
        }));
this.$el.find('#opentoall').val(this.model.get('opentoall'));
```

i am not sure what i am missing....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your model's opentoall attribute is a boolean, you need to convert it to a string. Try:

```
this.$el.find('#opentoall').val(this.model.get('opentoall').toString());
```